Problem adding record to renderer using N/render addRecord
I am working on a Suitelet that shows a check PDF in a new Window. Everything is working as expected except I've now hit a problem with rendering the PDF itself.
        const renderPdfTemplate = (pdfTemplateScriptId, paymentRecordObj, billData) => {
            const pdfTemplateObj = render.create();

            pdfTemplateObj.setTemplateById(pdfTemplateScriptId);
            pdfTemplateObj.addRecord({record: paymentRecordObj, templateName: 'records'});
            
            const data = { values: billData };
            
            pdfTemplateObj.addCustomDataSource({
                alias: 'billList'
                , data: JSON.stringify(data)
                , format: render.DataSource.JSON
            });
           return pdfTemplateObj.renderAsPdf();
         }


This is part of my Advanced PDF that makes me think the record isn't being successfully added to the renderer:  (Bill List Found shows up on PDF, nothing else if found)
                                <#if billList?has_content>
                                    ${billList.values[0].id} Bill List Found
                                <#else>
                                    Bill List Not Found
                                </#if>
                                  <br />
                                  <#if records?has_content>
                                    Records List Found
                                <#else>
                                    Records List Not Found
                                </#if><br />
                                 <#if record?has_content>
                                    Record List Found
                                <#else>
                                    Record List Not Found
                                </#if><br />

I can get my data from billList just fine but I can't seem to access my actual record.
Here is the code that is calling renderPdfTemplate:
                scriptContext.response.writeFile({
                    file: renderPdfTemplate(pdfTemplateScriptId, paymentRecordObj, billData)
                    , isInline: true
                });


// for reference this is how paymentRecordObj is being obtained, pdfTemplateScriptId is a hardcoded string and for this context billData is also hardcoded.

const loadBillPaymentRecord = (recordId) => {
            return record.load({id: recordId, type: record.Type.VENDOR_PAYMENT});
        }





I tried using addRecord() following the NetSuite documentation but wasn't able to successfully reference it when printing.

How are you creating paymentRecordObj, should be created by record.load(), are you getting any errors?

I've always had issues with render.DataSource.JSON.  I think the use case is likely not well documented.
Luckily you can just do:
pdfTemplateObj.addCustomDataSource({
  alias: 'billList'
  , data: data
  , format: render.DataSource.OBJECT
});

